# How do I run rsync in exec from php?

Tags: php, apache, exec, rsync

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

I can run this command in Terminal without any problem at all:

```
rsync -rtv source user@ip:/dest/
```

But when I try to run the same command with exec in PHP it doesn't work.

```
exec('rsync -rtv source user@ip:/dest/');
```

I have tried several tutorials this weekend but I can't get it to work, I think that the problem is that the apache user don't have the permission to run rsync but I can be wrong here.

This is one of the tutorials that I have tried that I think is my problem but I don't understand what to do:

https://serverfault.com/questions/248979/php-rsync-with-exec-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the user that is running php has no rights to the folder.
Find out which the user is and set it as owner if possible.

Comment: Alpix, thanks for your answer. The user seems to be www-data. Do you mean rights to source or dest folder? And how do I set www-data as owner?

Comment: www-data needs the right to read source and the right to write to dest!